# How to merge two objects of all properties in an array if it has same id in javascript?

Tags: javascript

JSON: (I have two same object properties in array. i would like merge all the property values of this array. I have added other case, if id gets changed, it should give like below. )

```
const array = [{
                 Lot_id:{ 
                          id:1,
                          qty_receive:30,
                          qty_return:5,
                          qty_remain:15
                         },    
                 qty_allocate:10,
                 remaining_qty:20
                },
                 {
                 Lot_id:{ 
                          id:1,
                          qty_receive:30,
                          qty_return:5,
                          qty_remain:15
                         },
                 qty_allocate:10,
                 remaining_qty:20
                },
                 {
                 Lot_id:{ 
                          id:2,
                          qty_receive:30,
                          qty_return:5,
                          qty_remain:15
                         },
                 qty_allocate:10,
                 remaining_qty:20
                }]
```

expected result:(updated my question)

```
const array = [{
                  Lot_id:{ 
                          id:1,
                          qty_receive:60,
                          qty_return:10,
                          qty_remain:30
                         }
                 qty_allocate:20,
                  remaining_qty:40
                },
                 {
                 Lot_id:{ 
                          id:2,
                          qty_receive:30,
                          qty_return:5,
                          qty_remain:15
                         },
                 qty_allocate:10,
                 remaining_qty:20
                }]
```

Comment: You would need to post what you tried too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can u try this?

```js
const array = [
                 { Lot_id:{ id:1, qty_receive:30, qty_return:5, qty_remain:15}, qty_allocate:10},
                 { Lot_id:{ id:1, qty_receive:30, qty_return:5, qty_remain:15}, qty_allocate:10},
                 { Lot_id:{ id:2, qty_receive:30, qty_return:5, qty_remain:15}, qty_allocate:10},                                
               ]
 function merge(array){
  var result = [];               
  array.reduce(function(res, value) {
    if (!res[value.Lot_id.id]) {
      res[value.Lot_id.id] = { 
        Lot_id: {
           id:value.Lot_id.id,
           qty_receive:0,
           qty_return:0,
           qty_remain:0,
        }, qty_allocate: 0 

      };
      result.push(res[value.Lot_id.id])
    }
      res[value.Lot_id.id].qty_allocate += value.qty_allocate;
      res[value.Lot_id.id].Lot_id.qty_receive += value.Lot_id.qty_receive;
      res[value.Lot_id.id].Lot_id.qty_return += value.Lot_id.qty_return;
      res[value.Lot_id.id].Lot_id.qty_remain += value.Lot_id.qty_remain;
      return res;
    }, {});
    return result
 } 
  
 console.log(merge(array));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const reduceArr = array.reduce((total, {Lot_id: {qty_receive, qty_return, qty_remain}, qty_allocate}) => {
  total.Lot_id.qty_receive += qty_receive;
  total.Lot_id.qty_return += qty_return;
  total.Lot_id.qty_remain += qty_remain;
  total.qty_allocate += qty_allocate;
  return [total];
});
```

**Update answer according to your updated question:**

```
const mergeArr = () => {
const newArr = [];
let tempId = 0;

array.forEach((item, index) => {
if (tempId !== item.Lot_id.id) {
  tempId = item.Lot_id.id;
  newArr.push(item);
} else {
  const lastItem = newArr[newArr.length - 1];
  const lastLot = lastItem.Lot_id;
  const newLot = item.Lot_id;

  lastLot.qty_receive += newLot.qty_receive;
  lastLot.qty_return += newLot.qty_return;
  lastLot.qty_remain += newLot.qty_remain;
  lastItem.remaining_qty += item.remaining_qty;
  lastItem.qty_allocate += item.qty_allocate;
}
});

return newArr;
}

console.log(mergeArr());
```

try the code here:

https://repl.it/repls/SparseUnfortunateLanguage

Comment: in this solution, before doing addition opertion need to check lot_id.. if it lot_id get varies, then this should not be work..

Comment: I updated my answer and added a link.
Please be advice that the website (repl.it, which is a great tool) is experiencing some issues at the moment, so if the link appear to be broken just try it later.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead,

```
let result = mergeElements(array);

console.log(result);


/**
  * function accepts the array of objects you need to merge by adding fields
  * */
function mergeElements(array = []) {
    let sumOf = [];
    if (array.length <= 1) {
      return array;
    } else {
      sumOf[0] = array[0]; 
      let index = 0;
      array.forEach(function (item, index) {
        if (index != 0) {
          sumOf[0] = iterateItem(item, sumOf[0]);
        }
        index++;
      });
    }
    return sumOf;
}

/**
  *function for indepth iteration of objects
  * */
function iterateItem(item, sumOf) {
    if (typeof item == "object") {
      for (let key in item) {
        if (typeof item[key] != "object") {
          if (typeof sumOf[key] == "undefined") {
            sumOf[key] = 0;
          }
          if (key == "id") {
            continue;
          }
          sumOf[key] += item[key];
        } else {
          if (typeof sumOf[key] == "undefined") {
            sumOf[key] = {};
          }
          sumOf[key] = iterateItem(item[key], sumOf[key]);
        }
      }
    } else {
      sumOf += item;
    }
    return sumOf;
}
```

I hope this will help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can check my solution for your issue.

```js
const array = [
  {
    Lot_id: {
      id: 1,
      qty_receive: 30,
      qty_return: 5,
      qty_remain: 15,
    },
    qty_allocate: 10,
  },
  {
    Lot_id: {
      id: 1,
      qty_receive: 30,
      qty_return: 5,
      qty_remain: 15,
    },
    qty_allocate: 10,
  },
  {
    another_id: {
      id: 1,
      qty_receive: 30,
      qty_return: 5,
      qty_remain: 15,
    },
    qty_allocate: 10,
  },
  {
    another_id: {
      id: 1,
      qty_receive: 30,
      qty_return: 5,
      qty_remain: 15,
    },
    qty_allocate: 10,
  },
];

const isObject = (value) => {
  return (
    typeof value === "object" &&
    value instanceof Object &&
    !(value instanceof Array)
  );
};

const result = array.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  const existingObj = acc.find((accObj) => {
    return Object.keys(accObj).every(
      (key) => Object.keys(obj).indexOf(key) > -1
    );
  });
  if (existingObj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
      if (isObject(obj[key])) {
        const innerObj = obj[key];
        const existingInnerObj = existingObj[key];
        Object.keys(innerObj).forEach((innerKey) => {
          if(innerKey !== 'id') {
            existingInnerObj[innerKey] += innerObj[innerKey];
          }
        });
      } else {
        existingObj[key] += obj[key];
      }
    });
  } else {
    acc.push(obj);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Your output is wrong . All id are 1 so  u have only one object ,but in your code there two and their ids are 2 even there is no id such as 2

Comment: @Çağrı thank you so much for informing that bug. I've already fixed that. Would you please check now?